# Mimic video chapter menu from Videos app using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I was under the impression that the default iOS movie player controller would automatically detect chapter markings in video files, *a la* the default iOS Videos app. I'm finding in my experiments that this does not seem to be the case.  I've tried adding chapter markers to a movie using SimpleMovieX (v3.11) and Subler (v0.15), and while these chapters are picked up by Quicktime on my computer, the MPMoviePlayerController in my iOS app (on the 5.1 simulator) does not seem to show a chapter menu.

The movie I'm trying to run this way is a *.m4v file.

Is there something I'm missing? I could simply be wrong in my expectation, but I'm wondering if for some reason iOS has stricter formatting requirements for chapter markers, or if there's something I need to set on the video player itself that I'm missing.

Comment: From my research, it's looking like this is actually not a feature of MPMoviePlayerController. I've submitted a bug report on this issue to Apple.